# strtotime thinks "first sunday next month" = wednesday?

Tags: php, strtotime

`strtotime` is kinda magical. And while I know it can't do *anything*, I always guess things before looking for the correct solution.

So I wanted to get the first Sunday and Monday of next month. I tried this:

```
strtotime("first Sunday next month")
strtotime("first Monday next month")
```

after formatting (`%d/%m/%y`) the results are:

```
12/11/2014
13/11/2014
```

Those are a Wednesday and a Thursday. What gives? I expected it won't work or give me the wrong Sunday, but what's a Wednesday doing there?

**update**

I don't need help figuring out how to get the next Sunday. I know how to do the correct calculations (I know how to look up the proper way anyway). My guess above was just me messing around looking for a shortcut. **I am wondering, however** why I'm getting this specific weird result which seems completely unrelated to everything I wrote

Comment: FWIW, `strtotime` is not a magic do-it-all function. It can parse *some* date formats and *some* special relative instructions. It won't always give you the *what-I-mean* result regardless of what you throw at it. You'll simply have to do a little more manual calculations here.

Comment: @deceze I know. I wrote as much in the question. I just think it's weird to get a completely irrelevant date (rather than, maybe, `false` or something)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo date('r', strtotime("first Sunday of next month")) . PHP_EOL;
echo date('r', strtotime("first Monday of next month")) . PHP_EOL;
```

It's very tricky but you need to make sure that your format is exactly described in the [Relative Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) section of the manual. In this case you want **ordinal space dayname space 'of'**. Otherwise, it's probably just doing two different calculations in sequence.

In this case, since the whole expression doesn't have a known format it's getting split:

1. Move to next Sunday: Sun, 12 Oct 2014
2. Move to next month: Wed, 12 Nov 2014

Test code:

```
echo date('r', strtotime("first Sunday next month")) . PHP_EOL;
echo date('r', strtotime("first Monday next month")) . PHP_EOL;

echo PHP_EOL;

echo date('r', strtotime("first Sunday")) . PHP_EOL;
echo date('r', strtotime("first Monday")) . PHP_EOL;
echo date('r', strtotime("next month")) . PHP_EOL;
```

*Disclaimer: I almost never get it right myself.*

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for a way to achieve that (I also need to check if today is before the first sunday of the current month, so I can't do it like that anyway). I'm asking why I'm getting the weird result

Comment: Yeah! That's what I was looking for. Something that'll make sense out of it. Thank you! =]

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
// strtotime("first Sunday", strtotime("next month")); // wrong
echo date("%d/%m/%y", strtotime("first sunday of next month"));
```

But outputs [invalid results for PHP 4.3 - 5.2.17](http://3v4l.org/kQV9v#v430)!

Comment: Again, thanks, but not what I'm asking for. I was wondering why I'm getting that weird a result. I know how to do the correct calculations (and I know how to look up the right syntax). What I'm trying to understand is how `strtotime` picked a Wednesday of all things.

Comment: You got a +1 for the "invalid" thing. I didn't know that it didn't work before 5.3